# Ascendingly Insertion in doubly linked list in Python

Tags: python, insertion

I need to--> insert(self, val)
Adds a node containing val to the list, keeping the list sorted in ascending order. In case of duplicates
the new element is inserted either before or after the existing duplicates. If val is not an int, a ValueError
is raised.
I already implemented the class node and the class doubly linked list and here is my code for the insertion.

```
   def insert(self, val: int) -> None:
      """Add a new node containing 'val' to the list, keeping the 
            list in ascending order.

    Args:
        val (int): Value to be added.


    Raises:
        ValueError: If val is not an int.
    """
    # TODO
    if isinstance(val,int):
       new_node = node(val)
       if self.size == 0:
           self._head = new_node
           self._tail = new_node
           self.size += 1
           return

       else:#iterating through the list to get the proper location

           current_node = self._head
           while current_node is not None and current_node.val < val:
               current_node = current_node.next_node



    else:
        raise ValueError
```

I iterated through the list to find the location,However i am stuck in the insertion.Any ideas? Am I on the right track?